# Meaning of <<= and |=

Tags: c, operators, semantics, bit-shift, logical-operators

What is the meaning of `<<=` and `|=` in C?

I recognise `<<` is bitshift etc. but I don't know what these are in combination.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just as `x += 5` means `x = x + 5`, so does `x <<= 5` mean `x = x << 5`.

Same goes for `|`. This is a bitwise `or`, so `x |= 8` would mean `x = x | 8`.

Here is an example to clarify:

```
int x = 1;
x <<= 2;         // x = x << 2;
printf("%d", x); // prints 4 (0b001 becomes 0b100)

int y = 15;
y |= 8;          // y = y | 8;
printf("%d", y); // prints 15, since (0b1111 | 0b1000 is 0b1111)
```